# Changing settings on iPad Pro selfie camera? (2018 11 inch model)

Tags: ipad, settings, camera, facetime

Apparently the selfie camera (FaceTime HD) can operate in both 30 FPS and 60 FPS modes. I haven’t found a way to change it. Is there one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To adjust the refresh rate and resolution of the selfie camera, you also have to adjust the video recording options of the main shooter too. Apple does not let you change the settings independently of one another.

**Go to**: Settings>Camera>Record Video> “1080p at 60FPS” or “1080p at 30FPS”.

You should see the results immediately in the viewfinder.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if that also applies if the main camera is in a 4K video mode?

Comment: If the camera supports 4k, I believe along with the two other 1080p options it will also list the 4k options too.